# Find out what is making an element focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is there any way of finding out what is making the first html element (input, textarea) gain focus?

I'm loading a modal window and can't seem to find the JS line where focus() is being forced upon this first element.

A solution is to blur() it right after loading the modal window, but I'd like to know what is triggering this focus. Perhaps some event listener embedded inline in the textarea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That tool may help : http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: I've found this being rather a feature of the browser than something in the code.

Comment: Which code do you use to load the "modal window"?

Comment: @w4rumy I'm using jqModal, but it's not autofocusing - havent' had this problem anywhere else

Comment: @Guillermo "but it's not autofocusing" - I thought the input gains focus and you want to avoid this? Did I get this wrong?

Comment: @w4rumy No, you got it right. I meant jqModal, wasn't to blame for the autofocus happening on the first field at the modal box. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the onFocus event on the element to analyze the returned event object

```
//using jquery 1.8 style binding with 'on'
$('#myelement').on('focus', function( e ){
  console.log( e ); // <--- e is passed to the anonymous function
});
```

The `e` in this code is an instance of the Event Object that is passed to the event handler.

Check out the jQuery document for the [Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), specifically check out the [event.target doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
>   or a descendant of it.

---

**Note: there are a number of ways to set the focus on an element that don't include any javascript calls.**

For example in html 5, you can [define the default focus](http://davidwalsh.name/autofocus) of a document using `autofocus`

[Some browsers may even set the default focus](http://nemisj.com/focusable/) to the first input element on a document, or using a number of other HTML attributes.

Javascript may not be the cause of your phantom focus.

Comment: you could also use console.trace() instead .. which will give you a backtrace

Comment: @qodeninja thanks for your reply! The odd thing is that the first input/textarea is getting focused **if** I call the function that loads the modal window from <button onclick="load_modal(..)" ../>, but if I call load_modal() directly from the console the 1st field will **not** be automagically selected.
I tried both tracing (@lostsource) and logging the event and I can't see what triggers the focus() event on the field. 
All tested in FF18 & Chrome 24

Comment: why dont you share more of your code with us in your question? the fact that you are using the button tag means ur using html5. That could be a hint. It also helps if you can tell us what kind of libraries or frameworks ur using.

Comment: @qodeninja I wasn't aware <button> was part of html5, and I tried setting the onclick attribute elsewhere (<div>) but it all gave the same result (even with defined tabindex) the 1st field was focused. So  not to waste more hours on this, the solution I've taken is to add an invisible input (<div style="visibility:hidden"><input type="text" size="1"></div>) before my textarea. Thanks for your help though :)